# Logout with a countdown progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1899214.aspx?If%20no%20activity%20for%2015%20minutes%20display%20an%20alert%20on%20web%20page%20and%20then%20either%20continue%20or%20logout) to logout users after idle time (when no click is received anywhere on the body). I am trying to combine that with a countdown progress bar [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/4PKEB/1/)

My Code below

```
#timeouts {
    display: none;
}
#progressBar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: red;
}

    #progressBar div {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 10px;
        line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
        width: 0;
        background-color: yellow;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body class="smoothscroll boxed pattern7 printable" onload="StartTimers();" onclick="ResetTimers();">
    <div id="progressBar"><div></div></div>
    <div id="timeouts">
        <h2>Session About To Timeout</h2>
            <span class="alert alert-warning">Alert! Logout in 4 Seconds</span>
     </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var timoutWarning = 10000; // Displa
var timoutNow = 14000; // Time
var logoutUrl = '/logout'; //
var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
    document.getElementById("timeouts").style.display = "none";
    progress(14, 14, $('#progressBar')); //This makes things go crazy
}

// Show idl
function IdleWarning() {
    document.getElementById("timeouts").style.display = "block";
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html(timeleft+ " s");
    if (timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(14, 14, $('#progressBar'));
```

It will work perfectly on page load. But when the function ResetTimers() is called, it is supposed to reset the progress function. But things go crazy with the progress bar showing random values. Please help me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Could you please try to create a `DEMO` of what you mean by _things go crazy with progress bars_?

Comment: I tried to. But my demo jsfiddle is not working. I have fine tuned down to this. function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) is still running with original values even if i try to run it again from inside Resettimers(). So the timeleft has two values, one from the reset timer call and the one from the original count down. So I need to break the loop from the orignal count down before calling it again in ResetTimer()

Comment: I figured out that the function below is still running using the original values to 0 even i try to run it again from ResetTimers()

function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
-----
};

Hence I am getting two values for the progress bar as there is two instance of this function running. How to break the first function before starting it again from the ResetTimer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this.

```
var timoutWarning = 1140000; // Display warning after 19 minutes
var logoutUrl = '/logout'; //
var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;
var progressTimer;
var timeleft = 1200;
var timetotal = 1200;
// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    progress(timeleft, timetotal, $('#progressBar'));
}
// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(progressTimer);
    StartTimers();
    document.getElementById("timeouts").style.display = "none";
}
// Show idl
function IdleWarning() {
    document.getElementById("timeouts").style.display = "block";
}
// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * 100 / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html((timeleft / 60).toFixed(1) + " m");
    if (timeleft > 0) {
        progressTimer = setTimeout(function () { progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element); }, 1000);
    }
    else {

        IdleTimeout();
    }
};
```

By assigning a variable to the setTimeout function call inside my recursive function and then clear it by clearTimeout(progressTimer) inside the ResetTimers() call. Thank you

Comment: This is working fine. Any way I can sync this timeout between multiple open tabs? Or Do i need to ask another question for that?